# Foreach drive letter array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm putting together a script that checks whether or not a logical drive is USB or an iSCSI target. And if it is ignore the drive letters associated.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType='3'" |
where-object{$_.DeviceID -ne $usbletters -and $_.DeviceID -ne $iSCSIletters} | %
{$_.Name} | out-file $kreports\avail.txt
```

My issue is that when multiple drives are detected of the same type they are simply ignored by the not equal to option. I'm assuming I need to do some form of foreach loop?

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic!

Here's the full script.

```
#Variables and Arguments
$kreports = "C:\Kworking\reports"


# Create kworking Reports folder
if (!(Test-Path -path $kreports))
{New-Item $kreports -type directory}


# USB Drive check
$diskdrive = gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"}
$usbletters = $diskdrive | %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF 
{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE

AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} | %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS

OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass =

Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} | %{$_.DeviceID}

# iSCSI Drive check
$iSCSIdrive = gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.model -match "iSCSI"}
$iSCSIletters = $iSCSIdrive | %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF 
{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE

AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} | %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS

OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass =

Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} | %{$_.DeviceID}


# Disk Information
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType='3'" | where-object{$_.DeviceID -ne
$usbletters -and $_.DeviceID -ne $iSCSIletters} | %{$_.Name} | out-file
$kreports\avail.txt


# Fix Output Line Spacing
$InputFile = "$kreports\avail.txt"
$OutputFile = "$kreports\availdisks.txt"

$Writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter "$OutputFile"
$Writer.Write( [String]::Join("`r`n", $(Get-Content $InputFile)) )
$Writer.Close()
```

Comment: The filter DriveType='3' already excludes USB drives, CD / DVD and Floppy. `$iSCSIletters` what is? a single unit letter value or an array of strings?

Comment: Rather than hardcoding the iSCSI drive letters, wouldn't it be better to use WMI to navigate through associations to get to the hardware controller and looking at its type (`Win32_IdeController` vs. `Win32_ScsiController`). This does mean following `Win32_LogicalDisk` → `Win32_PhysicalDisk` → `Win32_PnpEntity` (device entry for the physical disk) → `CIM_Controller` (bus controller, which will be either an IDE or SCSI device).

Comment: Christian - DriveType='3' unfortunately still shows USB drives as local storage, unless you are using Windows 8 or 2012.

Comment: Richard - What I'm trying to do is have the iSCSI and USB drive letters dynamically picked up as this script will be run over a few hundred servers. (I've removed the a & b drive lettering to as to not confuse people about what I'm trying to achieve. I've also added the full script so you can see what I'm doing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Win32_LogicalDisk`'s member `DeviceID` contains drive letter and colon. As the value is, say, `C:` and you test for equality against `C`, the `where-object` doesn't find anything.

Either include the colon on drive letters or use a regexp the Powershell way.

```
$disks = gwmi win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType='3'"
# Select all devices that do not have deviceids a,b,c,k or l, followed by colon
$avail = $disks | ? { $_.DeviceID -notmatch "[abckl]:"}
# Do something with filtered results
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. That has done the trick. Seems I was over-thinking things!